# Rotate multiline text with Columntext ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

How do i rotate multiline text in itextsahrp?

I have tried:

```
float x = 200;
float y = 100;
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(new Chunk("Test \n new", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL))),
                   x, reader.GetCropBox(i).Height -( y+400),500+x, y, 10, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_TOP);

ct.Go(); 

ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
    cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
    new Phrase(new Chunk("Test \n new", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL))), x, reader.GetCropBox(i).Height-y, 12);
```

`ct.SetSimpleColumn` shows multilie text but how do I rotate it?

`ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` does not show multiline.

Comment: I've already explained this when answering your previous question: instead of adding the `ColumnText` to `stamper.GetOverContent(i)`, create a Form XObject (using the `PdfTemplate` object). Add the `ColumnText` to this `PdfTemplate` and add that template to `stamper.GetOverContent(i)` using the `AddTemplate()` method that accepts parameters to rotate the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a C# environment on my machines, so I've written an example in Java, named [AddRotatedTemplate](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddRotatedTemplate). I have taken an existing PDF file with the words "Hello World", I've created a template/XObject with some text, and I've added that template/XObject twice using the `addTemplate()` method (once using only x, y coordinates and once using parameters that rotate the text with PI / 4 grades). As a result, the text added to the template is added twice; see [hello_template.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hello_template.pdf)).

This is the code:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // Get canvas for page 1
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    // Create template (aka XOBject)
    PdfTemplate xobject = cb.createTemplate(80, 120);
    // Add content using ColumnText
    ColumnText column = new ColumnText(xobject);
    column.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(80, 120));
    column.addElement(new Paragraph("Some long text that needs to be distributed over several lines."));
    column.go();
    // Add the template to the canvas
    cb.addTemplate(xobject, 36, 600);
    double angle = Math.PI / 4;
    cb.addTemplate(xobject,
            (float)Math.cos(angle), -(float)Math.sin(angle),
            (float)Math.cos(angle), (float)Math.sin(angle),
            150, 600);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

There may be easier ways to define the rotation in other variations of the `addTemplate()` method, but I'm an engineer and I am so used to using the transformation matrix that I never feel the need or desire to use any other type of method.

Comment: Thank you for this! It helps a lot. But in the second addTemplate method the order of the trigonometric functions is wrong. Right order would be cos() -sin() sin() cos(). Your example works fine for an angle of PI/4 but for any other angle the rectangle deforms rather than rotates.